# Fragmented/broken down Text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, typography, photoshop-effects

I'm wondering how to achieve the effect in this attached image where text is fragmented to various degrees, some to the point of illegibility while elements remain legible. I'm experimenting mainly with Photoshop but can try InDesign also.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in Illustrator very easily but this method should work similarly in Photoshop. Instead of using the pathfinder tool, in Photoshop you would just use the rectangular selection tool and delete.

In Illustrator, you start off by typing your text and then expanding it. After it's expanded you should ungroup it.

[image]

After that you can start "cutting out" segments of the text using the rectangular marquee tool, (<kbd>M</kbd>) and then using the pathfinder function minus front.

[image]

You would just continue doing this until you have your desired cut-outs.

In the image below I marked out the general shapes the artist used to remove more an more of the letter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no Automatic way of doing it, as you can see though it cuts off a bit more of each letter as it goes up. (in this case it also dows it in order, I didn't exactly do it like that)

I wrote out the text, then cloned it (Ctrl C, Ctrl V) and dragged it above the  text, now I just made some black boxes on the areas I wanted to cover, then selected my most recent line and repeated = (Clone and added some *more* boxes, to cover more of the text)

After each time I covered a bit more until it produced the desired effect:

[image]